# How to do an emit from different / another route?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using express js & socket.io to built my simple app.

So, there is website "a" using PHP that will post some data to my app (built using express js). There are 2 routes defined in app.js, they are :

- /send_voting_result -> Will receive POST data from website "a"
- /voting_result -> Will be accessed by user & I want to make it to be realtime in updating the voting result data posted to /send_voting_result

What I did here are :

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);    

...

// Receive POST data and do update the data to /voting_result route
    app.post('/send_voting_result', function(req, res){
      var result = JSON.parse(req.body.kandidat);
      io.of('/voting_result').emit('getResult', {votingResult : result.data});
    });

app.get('/voting_result', function(req, res){
    res.render('voting_result', { title: 'Express', msg: 'This is Result page'});
});
```

**voting_result.html**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('getResult', function (data) {
    console.log("Message from server : "+data);
  });
</script>
```

However, the "emit" process in this script seems not working :

```
io.of('/voting_result').emit('getResult', {votingResult : result.data});
```

I'm unable to retrieve data posted to /send_voting_result in /voting_result

Actually, I'm new in using expressjs & socket.io, so I try my best to achieve it by referring to some related tutorial, but it's still not working.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `io.of()` method you're using doesn't refer to the URL of the accessed webpage. It instead refers to a namespace that you can define when you create the socket:

```
// Client-side
var chat = io.connect('http://localhost/chat')
// Server-side
var chat = io
.of('/chat')
.on('connection', function (socket) { ... }) // will only apply to some connections
```

This feature is used for instance to multiplex multiple data streams on one WebSocket, see [Socket.io's documentation](http://socket.io/#how-to-use), section *Restricting yourself to a namespace*.

There are then two solutions for your issue:

1. Don't use namespaces at all:

   ```
   io.of('/voting_result').emit('getResult', {votingResult : result.data});
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   io.emit('getResult', {votingResult : result.data});
   ```
2. Define a namespace on the client, that you'll use on server-side:

   ```
   var socket = io.connect('/voting_result');
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Paul, the 2nd solution works on my local. So, by using namespaces we can separate the socket object we need, right ?